# How to create a calculated column using data from other tables in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have three tables(W,P,Q) each connected to the Primary key of another table(S). In order to calculate a field, I need to get data from the three tables(W,P,Q). I know that in SQL Server you can only create a calculated column with data from the SAME table.

I was wondering if there's any other way to solve my problem without merging the three tables into one. I had a project in Access with the same requirements and I was able to solve this problem using a query. I was trying to create a query in SQL server similar to what I did in Access, but I don't know how to add a column with formula in SQL Server queries.

I'm also using vb.net for the front-end of my application. So I also need to be able connect what I want to do in DataGridView Any suggestions would be helpful and sorry for any mistakes I'm new in stackoverflow and SQL server.

ACCESS VERSION:

```
SELECT 
   tblStudent.stud_LRN, 
   tblStudent.stud_Lname, 
   tblStudent.stud_Fname,          
   [tblPerformanceTask]![perf_WS]+[tblQuarterlyAssessment]![quart_WS]+[tblWrittenWork]![writ_WS] AS InitialGrade, 
   IIf([InitialGrade]<60,60+15* ([InitialGrade]/60),75+25*([InitialGrade]-60)/40) AS QuarterGrade,    
   tblStudent.stud_rec_ID
FROM 
   ((tblStudent 
   INNER JOIN tblPerformanceTask ON 
   tblStudent.stud_rec_ID = tblPerformanceTask.Stud_Rec_ID) 
   INNER JOIN tblQuarterlyAssessment ON 
   tblStudent.stud_rec_ID = tblQuarterlyAssessment.stud_rec_ID) 
   INNER JOIN tblWrittenWork ON 
   tblStudent.stud_rec_ID = tblWrittenWork.stud_rec_ID;
```

SQL SERVER VERSION:

```
SELECT 
   S.Stud_LRN,
   S.Stud_LName, 
   S.Stud_FName, 
   W.writ_PS, 
   W.writ_WS,    
   P.perf_PS,
   P.perf_WS, 
   Q.quart_PS, 
   Q.quart_WS
FROM 
   tblStudent AS S 
   INNER JOIN tblWrittenWork            AS W ON S.Stud_rec_ID = W.Stud_ID_FK 
   INNER JOIN tblPerformanceTask        AS P ON S.Stud_rec_ID = P.Stud_ID_FK 
   INNER JOIN tblQuarterlyAssessment    AS Q ON S.Stud_rec_ID = Q.Stud_ID_FK
```

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: There is no restriction is performing a calculation across columns from multiple tables in a query. If you are trying to create a computed column that is a different story, but in a derived column like you have in your access example you can do the exact same thing in sql server.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve?  An example of what you're expecting as a final product might help.  I am a bit confused if you just need a select statement, a column (as indicated by the title), or even if a view would serve your purposes.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish will help give us better solutions.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the columns with _PS and _WS for a calculation like Initial = sum of all _WS.

Comment: @Sean Lange Can you help point me in the right direction? I don't know how to make a derive column in sql server.

Comment: Look at the answer posted by SqlZim, that has two derived columns in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: @Euphemia do accept if the an answer help you out. sqlzim  answer should be accepted.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow how can you accept an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server 2012+ you can also use [`iif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx), but here is the `case` version:

```
select 
     S.Stud_LRN
   , S.Stud_LName
   , S.Stud_FName
   , W.writ_PS
   , W.writ_WS
   , P.perf_PS
   , P.perf_WS
   , Q.quart_PS
   , Q.quart_WS
   , InitialGrade = P.perf_WS + Q.quart_WS + W.writ_WS
   , QuarterGrade = case 
      when (P.perf_WS + Q.quart_WS + W.writ_WS) < 60
      then 60 + 15 * ((P.perf_WS + Q.quart_WS + W.writ_WS) / 60)
      else 75 + 25 * ((P.perf_WS + Q.quart_WS + W.writ_WS) - 60) / 40
      end
from tblStudent as S
  inner join tblWrittenWork as W 
    on S.Stud_rec_ID = W.Stud_ID_FK
  inner join tblPerformanceTask as P 
    on S.Stud_rec_ID = P.Stud_ID_FK
  inner join tblQuarterlyAssessment as Q 
    on S.Stud_rec_ID = Q.Stud_ID_FK
```